# How to copy folders from blob storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

The functionality I am trying to implement is copy paste files/folders from one source to another(same container). Can I use same method to copy folders like I do for copy files?
startcopyblob() throws error while copy pasting folders.

input:

newFileName:'new folder_copy1'
newFilePath:'603487d1e966a91fd86b6c11/spe9_rs_2021-03-17_17-14-38/output'
oldFilePath:'603487d1e966a91fd86b6c11/spe9_rs_2021-02-23_11-14-41/output/new folder'

error:

```
code:'CannotVerifyCopySource'
message:'The specified blob does not exist.
name:'StorageError'
requestId:'4a8a76bf-701e-0078-17c8-1b4439000000'
stack:'StorageError: The specified blob does not exist.
statusCode:404

Uncaught Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

code:

```
var host = sasurl.substring(0, sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"));
var containerName = sasurl.substring(sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"), sasurl.indexOf("?")).split("/")[1];
var saskey = sasurl.substring(sasurl.indexOf("?"), sasurl.length);
var blobService = storage.createBlobServiceWithSas(host, saskey);
pasteFiles.forEach(elem => {
var storageuri = host + "/" + containerName + "/" + elem["oldFilePath"] + saskey;
var blobName = elem["newFilePath"] + "/" + elem["newFileName"];
blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, blobName, err => {
if (err) {
console.log(err)
return res.status(500).json({
message: 'error',
status: err
})
```

.....
..

Comment: Could you tell me if sourceContainer and desContainer are in the same storage account and how you create sas token?

Comment: Yes, they are in same account. I am able to copy files but for folders ,throwing above error.

Comment: Is that  you directly copy a folder to another container?

Comment: storageuri='://host/container-name/603487d1e966a91fd86b6c11/spe9_rs_2021-02-23_11-14-41/output/new folder?sv=2019-1............3D'   blobname='603487d1e966a91fd86b6c11/spe9_rs_2021-03-17_17-14-38/output/new folder_copy1'

Comment: I am using node js,, blob service.

Comment: this answer dint resolve my issue but ya I used listblobssegmentedwithprefix() which listed all the files path and startcopyblob()which created folder for each filepath, anyways I accept this answer as it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure blob storage has a 2 level hierarchy - blob container and blob. It is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical scheme. It does not have a directory structure.   We just can specify a character or string delimiter within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy. So if we want to copy one folder with azure node blob sdk, we need to copy blobs in the folder one by one.

For example
sdk

```
npm i @azure/storage-blob
```

code

```
const {
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
  generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
  ContainerSASPermissions,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const accountName = "andyprivate";
const accountKey =
  "";
const creds = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  creds
);
async function test() {
  try {
    const sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("input");
    const desContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("output");
    const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
      {
        expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400000),
        containerName: sourceContainerClient.containerName,
        permissions: ContainerSASPermissions.parse("rl"),
      },
      creds
    ).toString();
    for await (const response of sourceContainerClient
      .listBlobsFlat({ prefix: "<your folder name>/" })
      .byPage()) {
      for (const blob of response.segment.blobItems) {
        console.log(`Blob name : ${blob.name}`);
        const sourceBlob = sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient(blob.name);
        const sourceUrl = sourceBlob.url + "?" + blobSAS;
        const res = await (
          await desContainerClient
            .getBlobClient(blob.name)
            .beginCopyFromURL(sourceUrl)
        ).pollUntilDone();

        console.log(res.copyStatus);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
test();
```

[image]
[image]

Besides, if you want to directly copy one folder from one container from another container, we can use azcopy implement it. For more details,  please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure-tools/azcopy-node)

For example

```
npm i @azure/storage-blob @azure-tools/azcopy-node @azure-tools/azcopy-<your system win32 linux win64>
```

code

```
const {
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
  generateAccountSASQueryParameters,
  AccountSASPermissions,
  AccountSASResourceTypes,
  AccountSASServices,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const accountName = "andyprivate";
const accountKey =
  "";
const creds = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
//create account sas token
const accountSas = generateAccountSASQueryParameters(
  {
    startsOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() - 8640),
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400000),
    resourceTypes: AccountSASResourceTypes.parse("sco").toString(),
    permissions: AccountSASPermissions.parse("rwdlacup").toString(),
    services: AccountSASServices.parse("b").toString(),
  },
  creds
).toString();
const { AzCopyClient } = require("@azure-tools/azcopy-node");
let copyClient = new AzCopyClient();

async function copy() {


  try {
    let jobId = await copyClient.copy(
      {
        type: "RemoteSas",
        resourceUri: "https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/input",
        sasToken: accountSas,
        path: "/<folder name>",
      },
      {
        type: "RemoteSas",
        resourceUri: "https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/outcontainer",
        sasToken: accountSas,
        path: "",
      },
      { recursive: true }
    );
    let status;
    while (!status || status.StatusType !== "EndOfJob") {
      let jobInfo = await copyClient.getJobInfo(jobId);
      status = jobInfo.latestStatus;
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    console.log("OK");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

copy();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the error once i add this code 

`const { AzCopyClient } = require("@azure-tools/azcopy-node")

C:\WorkArea\OSA-WEB\node_modules\@azure-tools\azcopy-node\dist\src\AzCopyClient.js:38
        this._envVars = options?.envVars || {};
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`